# The safest way to access GMail on mobile devices

Tags: email, ios

There are three ways to access your GMail account on iPhone or iPad devices:
1. Use safari browser
2. Use Apple's default mail app
3. Use Google's [Gmail app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gmail/id422689480?mt=8)

What is the safest way to access gmail account? How about stored (downloaded) emails in case of app usage? Is there anything user can do in order to increase email safety (use SSL for example)?

Comment: I think this is off topic,  or generally a boring question.  The answer is: "It doesn't matter, its all over HTTPS."

Comment: But app stores emails on the device, do you think they're encrypted? Can the app be compromised (so even HTTPS won't help?

Comment: If the device is compromised encryption won't help.  The attacker can just wait until you decrypt it for him.

Comment: Okay, and what is easier to compromise? Safari, Mail or GMail app?

Comment: Be careful,  with a loaded question like that you are asking for a flame war.

Comment: @Rook I disagree. Each of these might be storing its local cache of emails securely, or not. Also credentials may be stored securely, or not so much. I think it's a fair question.

Comment: @AviD♦ No one is stopping you from posting an answer.

Comment: @Rook yes, well I don't actually have any information on either of these (nor an iPhone/iPad to test on)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of these apps will use SSL in some flavor (probably https)  to contact Google.  Google doesn't provide another interface for good reason.

Everything can be compromised.  You can be hacked though your browser and it doesn't matter what device you are using.   Once the attacker is on your machine it doesn't matter if your email is encrypted.  The attacker can wait until you decrypt it,  or just take your password.

Comment: Okay, looks like I won't get more specific answer. I was aware of this general security overview, but thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an application specific password.  At least if it gets compromised, you wont have to change your regular password.

I'm not sure if it logs what device used it, but ideally it would do that.

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1173270?hl=en